# Alarm not showing notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

It shows notification only on API below 26. It doesn't show notification above API 26.

I'm new here,and do i need to add channel to get notification, if so how to add the channel.

I'm new to programming, it would help if posted answers with full existing code.
This is my RingtonePlayingService.java,thanks in advance.

```
public class RingtonePlayingService extends Service {

private boolean isRunning;
private Context context;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.e("MyActivity", "In service");
    return null;
}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{

    final NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), 
MainActivity2.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 
0);

    Notification mNotify  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("WAKE UP" + "!")
            .setContentText("No Alarm Needed My Passion Wakes Me")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

String state =  
Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getExtras()).getString("extra");

    Log.e("what is going on here  ", state);

    assert state != null;
    switch (state) {
        case "no":
            startId = 0;
            break;
        case "yes":
            startId = 1;
            break;
        default:
            startId = 0;
            break;
    }


    int startId1;
    if(!this.isRunning && startId == 1) {
        Log.e("if there was not sound ", " and you want start");

        int min = 1;
        int max = 5;

        Random r = new Random();
        int random_number = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        Log.e("random number is ", String.valueOf(random_number));

        if (random_number == 1) {
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, 
  R.raw.rins_3);
        }
        else if (random_number == 2) {
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, 
  R.raw.rics_2);

        }
            else if (random_number == 3) {
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, 
   R.raw.rics_1);
        }
  else if (random_number == 4) {
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,   
    R.raw.rs_4);

            }
        else if (random_number == 5) {
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, 
  R.raw.rics_5);


        }
        else {
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, 
 R.raw.rs_1);
        }
        //mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, 
 R.raw.r_1);

        mMediaPlayer.start();


        Objects.requireNonNull(mNM).notify(0, mNotify);

        this.isRunning = true;
        startId1 = 0;

    }
    else if (!this.isRunning){
        Log.e("if there was not sound ", " and you want end");

        this.isRunning = false;
        startId1 = 0;

    }

    else if (startId == 1){
        Log.e("if there is sound ", " and you want start");

        this.isRunning = true;
        startId1 = 0;

    }
    else {
        Log.e("if there is sound ", " and you want end");

        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.reset();

        this.isRunning = false;
        startId1 = 0;
    }


    Log.e("MyActivity", "In the service");

    return START_NOT_STICKY;

  }


  @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e("JSLog", "on destroy called");
    super.onDestroy();

    this.isRunning = false;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void showNotification(String msg) {

    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    PendingIntent contentIntent = null;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    //sound
    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    mBuilder.setSound(uri);

    //vibrate
    long[] v = {500, 1000};
    mBuilder.setVibrate(v);

    Random random = new Random();
    NOTIFICATION_ID = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: This is my full code please look into it [link](https://pastebin.com/2fT9Exjw) @veerendran

Answer (score 1):

Android O you need to create channel ID and pass the channel ID while creating notification builder.

You need to create notification channel something like this.

```
public  void createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager manager, String channelID, String description) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (manager.getNotificationChannel(channelID) == null) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, description,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

While creating Notification builder you need to pass channel ID

```
      Notification mNotify  = new Notification.Builder(this,<ChannelID>)
                .setContentTitle("WAKE UP" + "!")
                .setContentText("No Alarm Needed My Passion Wakes Me")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

                mNM.notify(notificationId, mNotify);
```

Comment: Do i need to create a separate java class for channel id? @Ramesh Yankati

Comment: No, you can create method for creating channel ID and pass the same channel ID to notification builder. See this method createNotificationChannel

Comment: Sorry i couldn't follow you can you please edit my code and resend the link [link](https://pastebin.com/2fT9Exjw) @ Ramesh Yankati

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `notify` after building Notification object as below.

```
mNM.notify(notificationId/*UNIQUE ID*/, mNotify);
```

Comment: What should i give for id and exactly where to place it? @Jaydip Kalkani

Comment: Place this line in next line of  `.build();` and you can give any int number (ex. 5664) for id

Comment: Still no notification. Do i need to do something in Manifest, i have alarm receiver and service tags. I want it to work on API above 26. @ Jaydip Kalkani

Comment: @5NIP3RXd If you want to work it on API 26 then you have to create notification channel as `Ramesh Yankati`'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet using your code.

```
 public class RingtonePlayingService extends Service {


   @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
     Log.e("MyActivity", "In service");
     return null;
   }


 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    final NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);

    String channelID =  "NotificationChannelID";
    String description =  "Notification Channel Description goes here";
    createNotificationChannel(mNM,channelID,description);

    Notification mNotify = new Notification.Builder(this,channelID)
            .setContentTitle("WAKE UP" + "!")
            .setContentText("No Alarm Needed My Passion Wakes Me")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
             mNM.notify(notificationId, mNotify); 

  }



    public  void createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager manager, String 
     channelID,   String description) {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
          if (manager.getNotificationChannel(channelID) == null) {
             NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, description,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Still facing error I've updated my code please look into it. @Ramesh Yankati